# Java array, prints something else

Tags: java, arrays, println

I'm trying to print the items from my array, but when I run the program, it prints out Orders:`testorder@4, testorder@5` and so on. Any tips on how I can fix it so it writes 123 Buy?

```
package hej;


public class TestOrder {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Order order1 = new Order("123", "Buy");
    Order order2 = new Order("456", "Sell");
    Order order3= new Order("231", "Buy");
    Order order4= new Order("987", "Buy");


    OrderRegister orderregister = new OrderRegister();


    orderregister.addOrder(order1);
    orderregister.addOrder(order2);
    orderregister.addOrder(order3);
    orderregister.addOrder(order4);


    System.out.println("Orders: ");        
    for (int i = 0; i < orderregister.getArrayList().size(); i++){
        System.out.println(orderregister.getArrayList().get(i) + "-");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add a `public String toString()` method to `Order` which prints the way you want.

Answer (score 7):

Because you don't have a `toString()` method defined for your `Order` class.

When Java tries to print an Object, it attempts to call the `toString()` method for that Object, if it can't find one it uses the `toString()` from the Object superclass.

And the Object `toString()` by default does this:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

which is exactly what you are seeing as output.

Answer (score 2):

Have `TestOrder` override the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate an object with a String (like in your `System.out.println(...)` statements), the `toString()` method is called on the object to convert it to a String first.

You need to override the `toString()` method on your `Order` class and have it generate the string form of the order.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you should expect, given that you haven't told Java any other way to convert an `Order` to a `String`.  Override `Order.toString()` if you want Java to use some particular way of converting an `Order` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You could/should try overriding the `toString()` method(which is called implicitly in your example) as others have suggested.

For example:

```
@Override public String toString()
{
return String.format("%s , %s", this.getID(), this.getAction());
}
```